# Magento 2 - How to override checkout-loader.js

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, knockoutjs, requirejs

I want to override magento_checkout/js/checkout-loader.js file with my custom module ( using require js ) here is my **requirejs-config.js** file :

```
var config = {
"map": {
    "*": {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-loader': 'Vendor_Module/js/checkout-loader'
    }
}
};
```

but it is not working.

I have flushed cache, deployed-static-content no but it doesn't load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to override Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-loader.js have to map with identifier rather then file name :

```
var config = {
"map": {
    "*": {
        checkoutLoader: 'Your_Module/js/checkout-loader'
    }
}
```

};